# localhost/private-sales what is the path to edit the default information?

Tags: magento-1.9, cms

At Magento link localhost/private-sales I'm getting below information:

> If you are a registered member, please log in here.
>
> Magento is the leading hub for exclusive specialty items for all your home, apparel and entertainment needs!

Please guide me the path where can I edit above information

[image].......

Comment: wow... in 1 min... 4 upvotes and 2 favourites. but only 2 views. Bingo !!! I suspect SPAMMING !!

Comment: I think so, but let me answer, this might be the CMS page. If so you can edit it from CMS > Pages > find private sales page there.

Comment: @GauravJain please put this as answer

Answer (score 2):

this is the CMS page. If so you can edit it from CMS > Pages > find private sales page there.